# Keyword Categorization Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, keyword-search, mlmodel

First of all i would like to thank everyone in advance.

Let me explain in brief what i want to achieve here, [https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YbEd.jpg][1], in the attached screen shot i have two columns one is "Description" & "Category", basically i wanted to build an python model which will read my Description column & tag it to the right Category.
For example if My description says "Not able to lunch zoom meeting" then Category will tag saying it is an "Zoom issue"

Looking something like training an model and reuse when required.

I am bit new to python programming language, someone could help me guiding how do i achieve this will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approves you could use to solve your problem, I would use the following approach:

#### Text Classification

Text classification is the process of assigning tags or categories to a given input text. Text classification is the foundation of NLP ( Natural Language Processing ) with extended usages such as sentiment analysis, **topic labeling**, span detection, and intent detection.

If you want to get an expert on your own I suggest this [article](https://www.toptal.com/machine-learning/nlp-tutorial-text-classification).
Otherwise, you can use MonkeyLearns-Classification API for your Project see [here](https://monkeylearn.com/blog/how-to-create-text-classifiers-machine-learning/)

Happy Coding,
Breadberry

Comment: Thanks - i wanted to expert myself not looking for 3rd party application.Any Suggestions , like how to start & which algorithm can i use.